# Getting a list of all unversioned files in a Git-controlled folder

Tags: git, bash, unix, version-control, grep

Getting a list of unversioned files in a Git-controlled folder is way more annoying than it needs to be. Unless I really suck at reading man pages, it doesn't look like Git provides a facility to perform this operation on its own.

There may be a more elegant way of performing this, but here's a one-liner I threw together for this task, in case anyone else ever needs to use it.

Edit: turns out there's a standard way to do this that already works well.

```
git ls-files --other [--exclude-standard]
```

Comment: `git ls-files --other [--exclude-standard]` does not work in `cygwin together with zsh` in case anyone uses it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Or...

```
git clean -dnx | cut -c 14-
```

If you don't want to see ignored files,

```
git clean -dn | cut -c 14-
```

Comment: @RyanLester: If we want to get pedantic about it, that line will fail to list a file named "Would remove " if such a file exists and is not tracked.  Don't use `g` unless you mean it.

Comment: Ah, right, thanks (I have a bad habit of appending `g` by default). Didn't mean to be pedantic, but more to leave something for others to copy and paste. Deleted my original comment to prevent accidental copies of bad code; correct version: `git clean -dnx | sed 's/Would remove //'`.

Comment: Update: turns out my Google-fu needed some work; best keyword in this case was 'untracked' rather than 'unversioned'. See text body for proper solution.

Comment: @sedulam: The `|` is called "pipe" and it feeds the output of the left command as the input to the right command.  The `cut` command is unrelated to Git.

Answer (score 9):

Actually, if you use `git clean` with the `-n` or `--dry-run` option, it will print out a list untracked files that it would have removed had you run it with the `-f` or `--force` option. Adding the `-d` flag includes directories that are either empty or contain only untracked files.

So you can run this command from within a git repository:

```
$ git clean -dn
```

And get output like this:

```
Would remove dir/untracked_file_1.txt
Would remove untracked_file_2.txt
```

Here's a bonus: It respects your .gitignore file as well, though if you add the `-X` flag, it will list only ignored files.

Comment: How can I remove untracked files? `git clean -f` does not work.

Comment: @Timo `-d` is for delete; `-n` is for dry-run. So omit the `-n` and maybe add `-f` and the files should be gone.

Comment: @tnt, thanks. Be careful, `d` is for directories, see platforms's answer

Answer (score 1):

wow, this post is on the brink of 10 years! Don't know much about git command line, but trying this command I get all untracked/unversioned files in my local repo:

```
git status
```

And get output like this:

```
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        /untracked_file_1.xxx
        /../untracked_file_2.xxx
```

Comment: Shows both - "Changes not staged for commit"/"Modified" as one list and "Untracked files" as a second list, what is funny to me that option `--untracked-files` doesn't seem to be needed; but `--ignored` does also include the ignored files.

Answer (score 0):

```
diff <(echo "`git ls-tree -r master | sed 's/.*\t//g'`") <(echo "`find . -type f`") | grep '> .*' | cut -c 3-
```

Comment: This will list all files in a submodule, including the versioned ones.

Comment: Oh, this will also list all the files in the `.git` directory.  You don't want that.